# DiscordSocketClient causes stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, wpf, discord.net

I'm making a Discord bot in C#, but with a WPF GUI (so I can read bot messages and offer support via bot). I am however having a problem with creating a DiscordSocketClient. I get a stack overflow exception: *System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'*. I have no clue how the code causes a stack overflow, especially since the same code works in normal console apps.

```
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private IServiceProvider _services;

    private string token = App.Current.Properties["token"].ToString();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Connect_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Connect_Btn.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); //This line throws exception and crashes program

        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        //await RegisterCommandsAsync();
        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Something about your code seems smelly. I don't think you want to initialize the Discord service on a button click. That's something you probably want once the program starts up and it should only happen exactly once. You're confounding your UI logic with dependency injection.

Comment: I tried a lot of other ways, this was just a debugging way. I've had it the main function as well, to be fair I feel as if I've tried every single combination.

Comment: There's really no way to tell just by looking at the constructor. I suspect the issue is not actually where you instantiate your client but rather when you create a singleton and then try to build it again. I'm not actually sure why you're using a service collection at all if you're just going to use the client directly. Try commenting out where you instantiate _services and see if it works.